# How to configure build step for maven goal in teamcity to run unit test

Tags: maven, unit-testing, intellij-idea, junit, teamcity

I use junit in my java project (developed using intellij idea) for unit test, and I want to configure build step in team city to run my unit tests only. I also use maven to build my project. It works when I set goals for maven to "clean compile" but I dont know how to configure build step to run unit tests.

Also in command line. when i run "maven test" it runs unit tests correctly and shows the failures.

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment on TeamCity, but I'll try to help anyway out of my maven knowledge.

So first of all `mvn clean compile` will never run your unit tests, because maven has a concept of ***lifecycle*** and testing phase is coming after compile phase.

When you run `mvn test` it will run all the face up to (including) the test phase so the unit tests will run as a part of maven default lifecycle.

Now you're asking about a "build step for running unit tests" from which I conclude that you need a separate step. In maven phase is nothing more than running a series of plugins. In maven plugin has goals, so you can run a plugin responsible for running unit tests directly.

In maven this plugin is called "surefire" and a goal is called "test", so you can run:

```
mvn surefire:test
```

Given the classes (production code and tests) are compiled, you will see that this only runs your unit tests. So this probably has to be configured in Team City.